# IDLE keeps restarting (RESTART: Shell) when running arcpy.CopyRaster_management

Tags: arcpy, geotiff-tiff, spatial-analyst, idle

I am trying to get a script to run to batch resample some TIFF files. I've used an almost identical script to resample GRID files with no issues. When I try to run it with a group of TIFF files the code stops with the first file with "RESTART: Shell" but no errors. Here is the code:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Input data source
env.workspace = r'C:\ArcGIS\GR 8573\tpw_tif_in'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Set output folder
OutputFolder = r'C:\ArcGIS\GR 8573\tpw_resamp_out'

# Loop through a list of files in the workspace
RSfiles = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")

for filename in RSfiles:
    print("Processing: " + filename)
    inRSfiles = arcpy.env.workspace + "/" + filename

    # This next line reduces a file name of the format "comp20180702.120000" to "807022" where the
    # first digit is the year (assuming all years 2018, 2019, or 2020), the 2nd & 3rd digits are the month
    # the 4th and 5th digits are the day, and the 6th digit the hour (assuming 00, 06, 12, 18 are the only choices)

    newname = filename[7:12] + filename[14]

    TempLayerFile = "resamp"
    
    outRaster = OutputFolder + "/" + newname

    # Process: Resample
    arcpy.Resample_management(inRSfiles, "resamp", "1 1", "BILINEAR")

    # Process: Copy Raster
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(TempLayerFile, outRaster, format="TIFF")

print "***DONE!!!"
print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

When I step through the process the I think the restart happens at `arcpy.CopyRaster_management(TempLayerFile, outRaster, format="TIFF")`.

When I searched for help I couldn't find any solutions I thought were applicable. It's especially confusing because with just a few minor changes to make it applicable to GRID files it works great.

Edit: changing the line `outRaster = OutputFolder + "/" + newname` to `outRaster = OutputFolder + "/" + newname +".tif"` solved my issue.

Comment: Try  outRaster = OutputFolder + "/" + newname +".tif"

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Comment: Please self-answer it to reduce number of posts with no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion by FelixIP solved my issue. Changing the line `outRaster = OutputFolder + "/" + newname` to `outRaster = OutputFolder + "/" + newname + ".tif"` did the trick!